# varsIgnorePattern to ignore unused class names

Tags: eslint

How can an ignore be set for the unused class names (there are a few) used in Side Effect modules?

```js
class Something {

  static {
    this.set();
  }

  static set() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

.eslintrc.json

```json
"no-unused-vars": ["warn", {"varsIgnorePattern": ""}],
```